# Keyboard extension loses height in iOS 10 when trying to size automatically in some cases

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, ios10, ios-keyboard-extension

You can download a sample project demonstrating the issue below here:
https://github.com/DimaVartanian/keyboard-extension-height-bug

When creating a keyboard extension and not specifying a concrete height for its components but instead anchoring them to the view/inputView so that in theory the system will determine their height based on environment and orientation, in some situations that height instead turns into 0 and the keyboard is crushed (with the exception of anything that has a concrete height such as a self sized label or button).

**This only seems to occur on iOS 10.** On iOS 9, the child views resized correctly to fit the default automatic keyboard height.

There are several scenarios this can manifest and this project demonstrates a basic one. It starts with the basic keyboard extension template with the default "next keyboard" button and the 2 size constraints it comes with:

```
self.nextKeyboardButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
self.nextKeyboardButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Next, we create a single other view that we want to fill the space of the superview without defining a concrete size for itself:

```
let anotherView = UIView()
anotherView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
anotherView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(anotherView)
anotherView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
anotherView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
anotherView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Now, let's say we just want to anchor this new view to the bottom of our keyboard superview. We would just do something like:

```
anotherView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

The result looks like this:

iOS 9
[image]

iOS 10
[image]

This layout is exactly what we expect. Now instead, let's anchor the new view to the top of our next keyboard button. We get rid of the constraint we just added and replace it with

```
anotherView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.nextKeyboardButton.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Logically, the resulting height should be the same (determined by the system)

The result is now this:

iOS 9
[image]

iOS 10
[image]

On iOS 9 it behaves as expected but on iOS 10, the flexible height view is resized down to 0 and all that is left is the fixed height button.

There are no messages about conflicting constraints. I'm trying to figure out what could be causing this and why it would only be happening on iOS 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has responded to my DTS ticket and told me to file a bug report, so this is actually an iOS 10 bug. I have filed a radar (#28532959) and will update this answer if I ever get a response. If someone else comes up with a concrete solution that allows me to still use autolayout to achieve an automatic height, answers are still accepted.

Comment: Did you get any answer ? We face the same issue, i would be glad to have an update if you have any.

Comment: Nope. Just a bug and you have to find a way to make your constraints without triggering it. Was just trial and error for me.

Comment: @Dima did you get any answer for that issue?

Comment: @Ramakrishna nope.

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved by setting a new constrain for the height.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like your solution was to hardcode a constant height. This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid as I am supporting every device size and orientation so I would like to let the system decide the appropriate height to use which is supposed to work but stopped working in iOS 10.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my workaround. It is a little laggy when the device rotates, but it will do the job until Apple fixes this bug. I first thought it had something to do with `inputView.allowSelfSizing`, but that variable didn't seem to change anything.

First, declare `heightConstraint`:

```
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

In `viewDidLoad`, Add your custom view:

```
let nibName: String! = UIDevice.isPhone ? "KeyboardViewiPhone" : "KeyboardViewiPad"
customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(customView)
```

Add a constraint for the width as you would do normally:

```
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: customView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
```

Add a constant constraint for the height:

```
heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: view.frame.height)
view.addConstraints([widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
```

Now comes the fix:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    heightConstraint.constant = view.bounds.height
}
```

As `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called every time `view.bounds` changes, it will handle orientation changes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. this is because of the Autolayout Constraints. Just remove all constraints. and set auto resizing.[image]

Comment: That's not really an option for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem for the custom keyboard extension in Xcode 8.2. This is caused by the `auto resizing`. In my case, I solved this in the below manner.

Initially, my custom keyboard have 3 views.
In this, I was fixed the trailing, leading, top and height for the first and last view. And place the middle view like in the image.
[image]

after that select the middle view and open the `show the size inspector` in the storyboard. In the `size inspector,` you will find an option `auto resizing`. In that select the constraint indicators for that view.

[image]

After selecting that you run your project in a device and it will work correctly without missing any view.

**Note: - It will work for both portrait and landscape modes. And mainly you don't have to give constraints for the middle view.**

Comment: @Dima check my answer. I'm also ended like you. But this processes solves my issue. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, best working solution is using "Proportional Height". For example, in my case, I finally ended with 2 views. Top one got 0.8 of height of superview, bottom - 0.2. It's not perfect solution, but you can still benefits from autolayout.

[image: Proportional]