# Keyboard Extension bug in iOS 10

Tags: ios10, custom-keyboard

**H/W and S/W platform for development**

- OS X El Capitan
- 4 GB RAM
- XCODE 6.3.2
- iOS 8.3
- iPhone 5, 5s, 6, 6+ and 6 after update iOS 10.0
- iPad 2 with iOS 9.3

We have recently developed an iOS (iPhone) app having custom keyboard with stickers.
Stickers downloads from cloud when keyboard is initialized.

Currently its developed in iOS 8.3 version and runs on iOS all later versions except iOS 10.0 update.

After updating iPhone to iOS 10.0, it has a weired issue i.e.. it shows only bottom footer part of the keyboard and doesn't render the keyboard view that has the stickers.

Not sure whether its an iOS 10.0 bug or some other issue at API deprecation or other.

Can anybody suggest if have any idea or faced the same kind of issue.

Comment: I have the same question.
Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694039/keyboard-extension-loses-height-in-ios-10-when-trying-to-size-automatically-in-s